# Choppy Sound in Chrome on Linux (flash or HTML5) but not VLC

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, alsa, pulseaudio

I currently have choppy sound on Chrome in Linux in both flash and HTML5 content, however VLC does not have choppiness. I am running Arch, using Chrome (dev channel), and using ALSA and pulseaudio; everything is updated to the latest version. Any ideas for how to debug this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the solution to alleviating the choppiness was removing pulseaudio and pulseaudio-alsa, configuring alsa correctly (for which I used asoundconf), and rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Either there is a software problem or the hardware can't handle it. I cannot tell from your question. Anyways, I'm going to give you some generic advice which hopefully should work.

**Debug PulseAudio/Choppiness fix**

1. Edit `/usr/local/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` as root.
2. There should be lines that read

   `#default-fragments = 8` and `#default-fragment-size-msec = 5`.

   Remove the hashtags (i.e. uncomment them)
3. You have to restart pulseaudio. The easiest method is to reboot.

**Generic Advice**

1. Make sure there are no CPU hogs in the background. The easiest fix would be a reboot.
2. Try changing the default playback device (Sound control in System Settings).
3. Make sure that your machine can handle the load! (Chrome is a heavily threaded application. Having a multi-core system/a fast system will greatly help.)

Comment: **Debug**
I tried this, but to no avail. I also tried (separately) adding a line `default-sample-rate = 48000`, which also did not help (though I think perhaps it changed the clicking/chopping subtly).

Comment: **Generic Advice**
1. This is  a brand-new i7 laptop. I rebooted several times, once after each edit of a configuration file (fortunately it doesn't take much time to reboot :P).
2. There are no "system settings"; I run a window manager, not a desktop evironment, and all configuration is done via configuration files. However, I did try changing the default playback, even going so far as to remove pulseaudio altogether (though that left me with no sound at all).
3. My machine can certainly handle the load. The only gui programs running are chrome and urxvt.